# Exit a script when there is file with certain name but ignoring a directory with the same name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If a file called “output” already exists, rather than a directory, the script 
should display an error and quit.

here is my code so far

```
for file in *
do
if [ ! -f output ]
then echo "error"
exit 1
fi
done
```

Comment: `output` -> `$file` and remove `!`.

Comment: what do mean by -> sorry i am beginner

Comment: Replce string `output` with `$file`.

Comment: `"$file"`, not bare `$file`, or else you'll have trouble when it's empty or splits into more than one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in *; do
    if [ "$file" = "output" -a -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "error"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Or

```
for file in *; do
    if [ "$file" = "output" ] && [ -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "error"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

And with `bash`, this one's preferred:

```
for file in *; do
    if [[ $file == output && -f $file ]]; then
        echo "error"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

If you want to check if the filename *contains* the word, not just exactly matches it:

```
for file in *; do
    if [[ $file == *output* && -f $file ]]; then
        echo "error"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: POSIX marks the boolean `-a` as obsolete; use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead.

Comment: @chepner Despite being obsolete I think most shells would still keep the feature. But you're correct about the other form.

Comment: Also, I didn't write it for POSIX actually, but for the original sh.

Comment: It's an extension to the POSIX standard, so there is no guarantee that an otherwise POSIX conformant shell need support it.

Comment: @chepner I think even before POSIX declared that extension, the original sh already has that feature.

Comment: As I understand it, the primary reason it's deprecated is that its behavior is sometimes unintuitive, particularly in cases where data values can be `(` or `)` -- leading to situations where using `-a` or `-o` in `test` can require the `"x$foo"` idiom for correct behavior; eww.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If data values are `(` or `)` -> I think that would only apply to wrong practices where people do `[ "$x" ]` instead of `[ -n "$x" ]`. Try `[ -n '(' -o -n ')' ]`. I'm guessing the POSIX team really made a blunder there not including it in the standard. They probably thought `&&` and `||` could be enough already. Good luck with subshell blocks `()` or dirty semicolon terminated `{}`. Just shows how POSIX is not a well-defined standard but just an outdated collaboration of old-school practices.

Comment: @konsolebox, FYI, the standard document goes into some depth around the places in the deprecated behavior where there be dragons; it's worth a read. Myself, I wholeheartedly stand with the proposition that `&&` and `||` *are* enough already; if they were the only acceptable grouping method for test, rather than `'('` and `')'` being recognized as test arguments when XSI-extended grouping is in place, there would be less confusion and fewer places for implementation bugs to hide around the XSI extensions in question.

Comment: ...not sure what you mean with respect to the "good luck with" the items in question. That said, I'm no fan of POSIX -- I agree with you that there's no shortage of places where the standard simply doesn't provide the facilities necessary for robust implementations.

Comment: This may be simplified without grouping but for instances that require it, with `-a` or `-o`: `[ <true_expr> -a \( <false_expr> -o <true_expr> \) ]`. Without `-a` or `-o`:  `[ <true_expr> ] && { [ <false_expr> ] || [ <true_expr> ]; }`. Imagine if condition levels go deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Why are we processing every file in the subdirectory?  Very Odd.

```
if [ -f output ]; then
    echo "'output exists and is a file"
    exit 1
fi
```

The [test](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) command (which is also `[`) (and is also *built-in* to most shells (see [bash](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) man page too) ), responds with a `TRUE` response for `-f output` only when **output** is a file.  You can check if it's a directory with `-d`.

```
touch something
if [ -f something ]; then echo "something is a file"; fi
if [ -d something ]; then echo "something is not a file"; fi
rm something

mkdir something
if [ -f something ]; then echo "something is not a subdir"; fi
if [ -d something ]; then echo "something is a subdir"; fi
rmdir something
```

If you try those commands, you'll get:

```
something is a file
something is a subdir
```

No point in iterating through the entire directory contents if you're just looking if a specific file/dir exists.